# JSlint on TypeScript code - can it still teach me to write better code?

Tags: typescript, jslint

Can using JSlint on TypeScript generated code still teach me to write better code? If yes en can you please provide one or two examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nope. Since the generated javascript is consistent between bad typescript / good typescript (e.g. missing semicolons).

For typescript there is a (recommended) ts-lint : https://www.npmjs.org/package/tslint Also has a grunt plugin : https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-tslint

Comment: thanks that's perfect. malevolent moderators can now close my questions, I got answer that really helped me.

Comment: hey danie.sedlacek - so mark the answer as correct -- give basarat come cudos, mate.