# jslint not compatible with Visual Studio Cordova tools?

Tags: cordova, jslint, visual-studio-cordova

I have been using jslint for a while in javascript projects edited with VS2013. But I am now experimenting with the 'Tools for Apache Cordova' plugin for VS2013 and jslint won't run with any of the .js files in the project. I get the error message
"The directory name *[project path]*\mymap.jsproj is invalid".
But 'mymap.jsproj' isn't  a directory, it's the VS2013 project definition file.

However if I load a .js file that's not part of the project into the same IDE, jslint runs on that OK. It also runs OK on a javascript project that isn't based on Cordova.

Just upgraded to VS2015 and have the same problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, if downvoting a question, explain why, so that I can improve it...

Comment: I don't know much about jslint right now.  But is this a problem because it assumes anything .js* is a javascript file?  Obviously, not everything .js* is a javascript file, for instance in your case, the .jsproj file.  Is there a way to exclude files from jslint function/feature?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem because JSLint works OK on a  javascript file that is not part of the project. In fact I can load a different project, then open a .js file from the original project, and JSLint now works on that same file.

Answer (score 1):

Quilkin,

You want to use `NPM` and `Gulp` or `Grunt` when linting.  I realize this changes your workflow, but it's a better solution.  `VS2015` has `NPM`, `Gulp` and `Grunt` built in and I believe you need web essentials for 2013.

Here's the github link on how to use `gulp-jslint`: https://github.com/karimsa/gulp-jslint

Many use `jsHint` instead of `jsLint`.
Here's the github link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jshint

More Information from abouit `jslint` vs `jshint` from stackoverflow: [Should I use JSLint or JSHint JavaScript validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803305/)

Basart answered a similar question about `TypeScript` [JSlint on TypeScript code - can it still teach me to write better code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827126/)

For typescript there is a (recommended) `ts-lint` : https://www.npmjs.org/package/tslint Also has a grunt plugin : https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-tslint

Comment: Thanks for the potentially useful links but I'm puzzled why I 'want to' learn to use these alternative tools. The JSLint plugin for VS generally works very well (and has 4 or 5 star reviews), it's just that it won't work with Cordova projects which by definition are going to be using JavaScript. So either I'm doing something wrong or there's a bug in VS which MS needs to know about. btw, Web Essentials for VS2015 has more bad reviews than good.

Comment: Quilkin, Here are a few links that do a good job at explaining the usefulness of these alternative tools.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/10/08/how-to-use-gulp-in-visual-studio.aspx http://joeriks.com/2013/08/06/can-i-benefit-from-grunt-for-my-visual-studio-based-web-development/ http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/grunt-npm-and-bower-in-visual-studio-its-awesome-right/

Comment: Thanks for that, I can now see that these tools will be very useful in a production environment. But I'm still in a learning environment (with JS that is, I have many years experience of C# and dotnet). If someone can show me the steps to install Grunt (or Gulp) into VS2015, and use it with JSLint./JSHint (can't see that in any or your links) then that would be a good start. I do want to see the results of the lint inside the VS ide.

Comment: Quilkin, Information about VS2015 and NPM, Bower, Grunt, Gulp is available, but it can be hard to find.  Here are two excellent videos that explain the basics: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-675 and http://jj09.net/building-large-scale-web-applications-with-typescript/  Also, twitter is a huge help.  The VS Apache Cordova and TypeScript team use it a lot.  Here are some names to follow: mkristensen ryanjsalva  basarat  typescriptlang Chuxel  DanWahlin kirupa JMatthiesen I hope this helps

Comment: DeanB, I really appreciate your trying to help and would like to mark my question as answered. But I tried the steps in the first video you mentioned and it was a pretty bad experience. See [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80f181a0-61d3-4768-be19-367abbb13aa3/vs-2105-rc-integration-of-bower-and-grunt?forum=visualstudiogeneral) for details. BTW I don't suppose you could reverse the downvote for my question; I still don't know why it was downvoted.

Comment: Chris, Sorry to hear you're having problems.  I'm using VS2015Pre every day on Windows 8.1 and I've had occasional problems. I read the link you posted and I can see a few potential issue.  1st: Don't even try VS2015PRE on Windows 10.  Two(2) unfinished programs (VS and Win 10) can only lead to problems. 2nd: Use the View > Output to view for build errors when VS isn't crashing. It generally has all the information on why it's crashing. 3rd: Make sure all VS2015 options were selected when installing.  I set the vote back to 0.  Also, if you're familiar with C#.NET, have you looked a Xamarin?

Comment: DeanB,  I only tried it on my Win10 testbed to see if the problems were caused by old stuff on my Win7 PC - which has had VS2005,8,10, 12 and 13 on it in the past! I did try Xamarin about 2 years ago but was disappointed to find that the user-interfaces still needed doing separately in ios and android. Then I discovered PhoneGap/Cordova so started learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to say that I alerted the JSLintNet developers to the issue and it has now been fixed! [latest beta](https://github.com/benquarmby/jslintnet/releases)